# Google App Engine Launcher Invalid PHP Configuration

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am attempting to deploy an application to my GAE instance, but cannot get the App Engine Launcher to work. I just installed the latest version of it and Python (2.7.4). When I attempt to launch and browse to my application on the local server, or when I attempt to deploy it to my GAE instance, I receive the same error message:

```
The PHP interpreter specified with the --php_executable_path flag 
("C:\dev\Google\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86\php-cgi.exe") is not 
compatible with the App Engine PHP development environment.

"C:\dev\Google\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86\php-cgi.exe -v" returned an error [-2]

Sat Aug 29 09:23:54 2015 (2316): Fatal Error Unable to write base address
```

FWIW, I do not actually even care about installing and running the application locally. All I want to do is deploy it. Why does my local PHP configuration even matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter, just use appcfg.py to push the application to production and skip the launched all together.

Comment: But that is the problem. It won't push to production. I get the same exact message trying to launch it locally, or when I try to deploy to production.

Comment: Also, shouldn't an install of a PHP App Engine SDK kind of have a working PHP install out of the box? Just sayin'.

Comment: of course it should - but that doesn't explain why it does no work with appcfg.py that doesn't invoke the PHP binary. How are you invoking appcfg.py?

Comment: I tried both from the GAE Launcher GUI and from the command line, and both resulted in that error. After a couple of reinstalls, the issue has disappeared.